# Locate a label on a form using relative position in Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, label, controls

I have a winforms with a label on the main form and I am looking for a way to set the label in % of the form size.  So, even if the form is re-sized and the label is set to y = 10% and x = 10%, not matter how the form will be re-size the label remains to the same location.  I have tried to use the x and y location, but does not work.  Thank you for any help and advice.

EDIT:

Let's say I have an image on my form and the label is set to just above IP Network. So, when the form is re-sized the label should also adjust and still be more or less above the IP Network.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "*I have tried to use the x and y location, but does not work*". What exactly have you tried and what problem have you faced? Have you tried to handle Form_Resize? Show some of your efforts, please.

Comment: Just to clarify: You want the label to always be 10% from the left and 10% from the top?

Comment: @BerndLinde If is set to 10% then yes.

Comment: It sounds more like you are looking to anchor/dock your label/controls

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Thank you for the comment and I know what you mean, but if the reader does not know what means setting a control relatively, the code would just make more confusion.

Comment: how many labels are you looking to set.. if there are more than one and you do not want to hard code this based on the Object name then look at doing this with a `foreach(Control n in Controls)` and check if the Control is `Label` as well as your form mode in regards to if it is Maximized etc... hope this make sense to you as well

Comment: @Sayse, using anchor is wrong.  If the form is re-sized, the label should always be 10%; if the form is 500, 10% and if the form is 1000 also 10%.

Comment: You have two options: either do it programatically, in the resize event handler, or set up some `TablePanelLayout`s and do some fancy footwork with the layout.

Comment: @MethodMan the label are added programatically, so can be 1 or many.  I know that it is not something simple and most of the reader just jump to a simple conclusion, but it is not that simple.

Comment: @doro Your goal is still unclear to me. You wrote: "*So, even if the form is re-sized and the label is set to y = 10% and x = 10%, not matter how the form will be re-size the label remains to the same location.*" - but in fact it's not true. For width = 500 10% will be 50 and for 1000 it will be 100 - so label will not in the _same_ location.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev are you aware what is percentage? 10% of 500 is not 10% of 1000.  The point is the label must be 10% of the form, not matter if it is 200, 500, 800 and....

Comment: @MethodMan if you and most do not understand is not my fault.  Who does not understand should just give-up.

Comment: @doro What is "10% of form" you're talking about? Form is not an abstract thing, it has width and height. Is your label location equals to 10% of width/height? Then it will be 10% of 200, 500, 800 and so on - this will give us location with one of dimensions equal to 20, 50 and 80 respectively - so location *will* change on resize. Or it's just "some magical 10%"?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this, is to handle the [`ResizeEnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend) event of the form.
Inside this event, you can then calculate the relative position as follow

```
private void SampleForm_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  lblSample.Location = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(((double)this.Size.Width * 0.1)), Convert.ToInt32(((double)this.Size.Height * 0.1)));
}
```

Naturally this setting can be added to a refactored method that takes a `Size` and % value in and outputs a `Point` object for easier reuse across the solution.

Comment: Still does not do what I need.  I just update the post and I hope is clear now.

Comment: An image does not change in percentage, it changes in scale. So trying to move a label percentage wise will not work for most resizing. What you need is a way of tracking certain parts of the images and positioning accordingly.

Comment: If that works would solve my problem.  Do you mind for an example?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience in graphical tracking or where to start, so I cannot help with that. I would also recommend you either close/delete your question and ask a new one specifically regarding moving controls according an underlying image, or edit this question to reflect that